# Making master password and storing it on android device

Tags: java, android, password-protection

I'm currently working on an app, and on the home screen, there should be something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqzLw.png
So my question is: how do i store that data in the android device?
I did not find anything helpfull on google, all i got is mysql data storage.
Thanks.

Comment: Please search in the goole about 'SharedPreferences for android'.

Comment: If you're actually storing passwords, I would spend some (a lot) of time researching security and encryption.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SharedPreferences to easily save and load simple values such as Strings, see below:

**Saving a String**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("app", MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor edit = prefs.edit();
edit.clear();
edit.putString("password", txtPass.getText().toString().trim());
edit.commit();
```

**Loading**

```
SharedPreferences userDetails = context.getSharedPreferences("app", MODE_PRIVATE);
String pass = prefs.getString("password", null);
```

If you're storing passwords you might want to look into more secure methods or use encryption/decryption techniques when saving and loading.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shared Preferences, but it's not adviced to save sensitive informations (such as passwords) in a phone.

Even you would encrypt a password, it could easily be decrypted back because Android apps can easily be decompiled.

Comment: what do you suggest then?